# Read and modify parameters of the entire TCP/IP protocol stack

Tags: android, tcp, parameters

I am trying to extract some paramaters from the TCP/IP protocol stack from an Android device.  The parameters are like:  the value of the 802.11 contention window at time *k*, the value of the TCP Congestion Window at time *k* and so on.

Have you any suggestions, link or guide on how to read those parameters? Do I need to operate at kernel level?